# Creating an environment to put another environment instance in vbox

Tags: environments

I have an environment (defined below). I would like to keep the whole environment instance from splitting across pages. One solution I came across is to wrap it in \vbox. So, my problem boils down to creating an environment that wraps another environment's instance in a vbox. Any help greatly appreciated :)

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise}{m}
{
} 
{ 
    Write your answer here
    \vskip #1cm
}
```

Comment: Are you just looking for a variation on `minipage`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\vbox\bgroup` at the beginning and `\egroup` and the end. I don't know about `\NewDocumentEnvironment`, but normal LaTeX2e environments don't allow parameters where you have the `\vskip`. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{exercise}[1]{%
    \def\exerciseskipamount{#1cm}%
    \vbox\bgroup
}{%
    \par
    Write your answer here.\par
    \vspace{\exerciseskipamount}%
    \egroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}{8}
Here is the first exercise.
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}{8}
Here is the second exercise.
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}{8}
Here is the third exercise.
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

If you compile, you'll see 2 exercises on the first page and one on the second. Each of them is wrapped in a `\vbox`.

*Of course, there are other packages for writing exercises that may fit your use case without you having to reinvent the wheel. Search TeX SX to find those.*

Comment: thanks! \vbox\bgroup .... \egroup works perfectly :) (even with NewDocumentEnvironment. I will look for existing templates for exercises.